# Java: get list of group on facebook using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I'm writing an application to get all group data that the user currently joining. But i don't know why it's only working for my facebook account (owner of app, too), for other account, the list return null.

This is the code i use to create url for user to login

```
    AppInfo appInfo = new AppInfo();
    String appId = appInfo.getAppId();
    String redirectUrl = URLEncoder.encode(appInfo.getRedirectUrl(), "utf-8");
    List<String> list = appInfo.getPermission();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String permission : list){
        if(builder.length() > 0)
            builder.append(",");
        builder.append(permission);
    }
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?display=popup&client_id="+appId+
            "&redirect_uri="+redirectUrl+"&scope="+builder.toString();
```

Action when login success (get the access token):

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/success")
public ModelAndView success(@RequestParam(value = "code") String authorizationCode) throws IOException{
    AppInfo appInfo = new AppInfo();
    String appId = appInfo.getAppId();
    String secretKey = appInfo.getAppSecret();
    String redirectUrl = URLEncoder.encode(appInfo.getRedirectUrl(), "utf-8");

    WebRequestor wr = new DefaultWebRequestor();
    WebRequestor.Response accessTokenResponse = wr.executeGet(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
            + "&client_secret=" + secretKey + "&code=" + authorizationCode);

    FacebookClient.AccessToken token = DefaultFacebookClient.AccessToken.fromQueryString(accessTokenResponse.getBody());
    String accessToken = token.getAccessToken();

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("success");
    mav.addObject("authorizationCode", authorizationCode);
    mav.addObject("accessToken", accessToken);
    return mav;
}
```

And the last is Action to display list of group:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/facebookData", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String autoFacebook(@RequestParam("accessToken") String accessToken, Model model){
    FacebookClient fbClient;        
    Post firstGroupPost = null;
    fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_3);

    Connection<Group> group = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/groups", Group.class);
    if(!group.getData().isEmpty()){
        Group firstGroup = group.getData().get(0);

        Connection<Post> groupPost = fbClient.fetchConnection(firstGroup.getId()+"/feed", Post.class);
        firstGroupPost = groupPost.getData().get(0);
    }

    model.addAttribute("firstGroupPost", firstGroupPost);
    model.addAttribute("group", group);
    return "facebook";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_group` permission is an extended permission. Therefore, to use it with another user than an admin/tester/developer of the respective app, the app need to go under Login Review.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

But you'll have a problem here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference (`user_groups`)

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Comment: so... can i use user_groups permission after submit review to Facebook? @Tobi

Comment: You won't get it approved if you're building your application for one of the mentioned platforms.

Comment: `user_groups` permission will be _completely removed_ on Tuesday, October 6, 2015 – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations